# How to check if syncfs is available and access O_DIRECT?

Tags: c++, linux

How can I check if syncfs is available, and access `O_DIRECT` at the same time?

per https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html

> The `O_DIRECT`, `O_NOATIME`, `O_PATH`, and `O_TMPFILE` flags are Linux-
> specific.  One must define `_GNU_SOURCE` to obtain their
> definitions.

so in order to access `O_DIRECT`, it seems I have to define *_GNU_SOURCE* myself. However according to https://linux.die.net/man/2/syncfs

> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)): syncfs():
> _GNU_SOURCE

in order to check if syncfs is available, I have to check if _GNU_SOURCE is defined?

Now if I do

```cpp
#define _GNU_SOURCE
int handle = open(argv[0], O_RDWR
#ifdef _GNU_SOURCE
| O_DIRECT
#endif
);
#ifdef _GNU_SOURCE
syncfs(handle);
#endif
```

it will miss-compile on Cygwin because syncfs is not available but the `#ifdef` check thinks its available because i defined `_GNU_SOURCE` myself. However if I do

```
int handle = open(argv[0], O_RDWR
#ifdef _GNU_SOURCE
| O_DIRECT
#endif
);
#ifdef _GNU_SOURCE
syncfs(handle);
#endif
```

I guess `O_DIRECT` will be erroneously omitted even when supported because i didn't define `_GNU_SOURCE` myself? now I'm confused. I don't see how i am supposed to safely check if O_DIRECT is available, and safely check if I can use `syncfs()`, at the same time. help?

Comment: You should `-D_GNU_SOURCE` if you know that syncfs is available.  Otherwise, don't.

Comment: You need to define feature-test macros *before* you include the header files checking for them.

Answer (score 1):

> in order to check if syncfs is available, i have to check if `_GNU_SOURCE` is defined?

No, this is a misunderstanding of what "*feature test macro*" means in the context of the (g)libc.

The feature test macro is something that is or isn't defined *by you* before including any header in a translation unit. The libc headers then exposes only those features to your translation unit for which you have defined the corresponding feature test macro or chooses behavior based on the defined macros. This makes sure that the name of non-standard entities do not clash with user-defined entities of the same name and that non-standard behavior does not break standard-based programs that should be portable.

See [`man feature_test_macro`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) for details.

These macros don't tell you anything about which features are *supported* by the system, only which are *exposed if supported* in the current translation unit.

To check whether a function is supported, you are expected to use a test program that defines the feature test macro and tries to use the function in question. Then in the configuration phase of your build system you should test whether the program can be compiled and linked. If that works, the function is supported.

Build systems have functionality to do this, e.g. autotools generally uses this approach and CMake has [`check_symbol_exists`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckSymbolExists.html) for that purpose.

Alternatively you can hardcode requirements on platform and glibc versions, etc., for which you know that the function is or isn't supported.